# Connecting to wamp server from different pc

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, wamp

I have made a webpage. It makes use of mysql. It works fine if i access it from my system(localhost).I have uploaded my webpage on server for my friends to connect to it. However I am not able to connect it. I have gone through other questions posted here about the related topic. I tried to rectify the problem with the knowledge i have gathered reading the comments.
like putting the wamp server online, including this:

```
    <Directory c:/wamp/www/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

however m still not able to connect it even from my pc after hosting it on the server. i have made use of a ftp software to transfer my files. my php code to connect to mysql:

```
mysql_connect('localhost:3306', $user, $pass) or die ("Connection Failed". mysql_error());
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) this is the error i receive

Comment: `your_ip_address:3306`..try this

Comment: how did you manage to put the wamp server online ? Also keep in mind PHP has deprecated the use of mysql_connect. Instead use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar - I am getting this error when i used my ip address Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_ip_address'

Comment: @Sid - by right clicking the tray icon of wamp there is an option to put online.

Comment: @Sid - sorry by left clicking

Comment: @ik024 you cant connect to your local db from an online server. You need to have a db on the online server. And that option in WAMP is not for deploying WAMP online.

Comment: @Sid can u tell me how to use/access online db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to follow the below steps:

1.in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"  //add your wwwroot folder path (this is Xampp example)
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

2.Open httpd-vhost.conf and add:

```
    ##</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost Name:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/wwwroot/
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/wwwroot/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin (any@email.com)
    ServerName (IP address or FQDN)
    </VirtualHost>
```

3.The most Important step is to add an exception for the used port(80 in this example) on windows firewall.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: where can i find httpd-vhost.conf? i can find oly httpd.conf in my wamp tray icon

Comment: try here :
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: and maybe this [Link](http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp) can be useful for you.

Comment: Sorry for being such a baby but in th 2step. In my file oly these are present     <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

Comment: and these
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

Comment: should i copy and paste the step 2 of urs with required modifications or should i modify my existing file as it is

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com //here you put your wwwroot file
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/wwwroot/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin (any@email.com)
    ServerName (IP address or FQDN) //put the IP of your server
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: can you provide me with your server IP Address and your wwwroot (which include the site files)??

Comment: I am using Mokia pc suite to connect to internet i saw the properties it says ur server ip is : 0.0.0.0 (donno if its correct) and my wwwroot is c:/wamp/www

Comment: i have gone thru the link u hv mentioned bt still getting the same error Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on.....

Comment: go to command prompt and type " ipconfig " that will give you the IP Address of your server.

Comment: yup did that wwwroot i hv dout in this when i left click on the tray icon of wamp there is the option localhost that is reffered to C:/wamp/www   but the htdocs which u hv mentioned in ur above steps is present in apache folder. which exactly is the wwwroot?

Comment: htdocs is a xampp wwwroot folder,and since you're using wamp then you should use C:/wamp/www instead of htdocs.

Comment: okay understood, ok one more thing instead of using wamp or xampp is there any way around? coz its very confusing to keep changing the files for each n every thing.

Comment: maybe consider buying a host plan from any company that can host the website and the files,so it'll be accessible for you and your friends,not only in office